# Center Latex lstlisting

Tags: latex, listings

This is driving me crazy.

I want to center a lstlisting in LaTeX.

After 3 hours attempting here's some code:

```
\lstset{ %
    caption=Descriptive Caption Text,
    label=lst:descr_capti_text,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\bfseries,
    frame=tb,
    linewidth=0.6\textwidth
 }
\centering\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{lstlisting}
printf("this should be centered!");
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
```

This is putting the lstlisting on the center but not its caption, that goes to the right. If I take out the tabular, then caption gets centered but the code goes to the left! :(

Thank you.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention the [LaTeX StackExchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2148/tex-latex-and-friends?referrer=5z6F4dAmVScN5QfMOt5KEg2) since once that takes off, it'll be the best place for questions like this.

Answer (score 39):

Instead of using linewidth you should consider to use **xleftmargin** and **xrightmargin** (cf. `texdoc listings`, Chapter 4.10). The following code works without any center or minipage environment:

```
\lstset{
  caption=Descriptive Caption Text, 
  basicstyle=\footnotesize, frame=tb,
  xleftmargin=.2\textwidth, xrightmargin=.2\textwidth
}
\begin{lstlisting}
    printf("this should be centered!");
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I was looking for. In my case, I used a negative value on `xrightmargin`so I could move the lslisting frame around...

Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 8):

Your caption is actually centered over the listing. You are just making the lines that run along the top and bottom of your listing only `0.6\textwidth` long. This makes it appear as if the caption was off-center. Also, your `\centering` doesn't center the listing (visible if you don't shorten the lines below and above).

This should work:

```
\begin{center}
  \lstset{%
    caption=Descriptive Caption Text,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\bfseries,
    frame=tb
  }
  \begin{lstlisting}
    printf("this should be centered!");
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{center}
```

You don't explain why you want the delimiting lines to be `0.6\textwidth` long. If
you actually wanted to set the width of your listing to be that value, your
approach doesn't do what you want. Use something like a minipage to set a width
for the whole listing.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \lstset{%
      caption=Descriptive Caption Text,
      basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\bfseries,
      frame=tb,
    }
    \begin{lstlisting}
      printf("this should be centered!");
    \end{lstlisting}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Although like Akim, I found it worked with the minipage within the center environment.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. The listing won't move.

Comment: Using `\begin{center}` doesn't have any effect for me centering the listing.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, what did work for me is the converse: putting the minipage inside the center environment.